# IValueConverters and MockData

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, valueconverter

I am trying to create an `IValueConverter` that takes an `enum` and spits out a URI. The converter does work at runtime as expected. However the XAML Designer trows me an error saying:

> Object must be the same type as the enum. The type passed in was 'Mocks.WarframeHelper_Model_Enumerations_15_1293735+RelicTypes'; the enum type was 'WarframeHelper.Model.Enumerations+RelicTypes'.

I have a simpler version of my model with the properties I only need at design time but the `enum` used is exactly the same (or at least should be). Is there anyway around this.

Here is the code for the `IValueConverter` (I am just getting the hang of those things so if I am doing something wrong feel free to correct me)

```
public class NameToUriConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Enumerations.RelicTypes), value))
        {
            return new Uri("/Assets/RelicIcons/Relic_" + (value).ToString() + ".png", UriKind.Relative);
        }
        else return new Uri("/Assets/Placeholder.png", UriKind.Relative);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value as string;
    }
}
```

and here is the custom data type that I use for the mock data:

```
public class Sample_RelicModel
{
    public Uri ImageUri { get; set; }
    public bool isVaulted { get; set; }
    public Enumerations.RelicFlavors Flavor { get; set; }
    public Enumerations.RelicTypes Type { get; set; }
    public Enumerations.DropRearity Rearity { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Sample_PrimeItem_Component> DropTable { get; set; }
    private int count;
    public int Count
    {
        get { return count; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
            {
                count = value;
            }
            else MessageBox.Show("You don't have enough relics", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
    public Sample_RelicModel() { }
}
```

Again the converter works as expected at runtime however the XAML designer does not like it because of the mock data.

Comment: Do the casing match? take a look at the remarks here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Nkosi that is the problem, they do not match. The runtime enum is of type (Enumerations+RelicTypes) however the design time one is (Enumerations_15_1293735+RelicTypes) which is where the problem comes from. I can confirm that both the Runtime data type and the design time datatype both have a 'using Project.Model' (which is where Enumerations lives), so it should be the same type unless visual studio creates it's own data type based on the one I created

Comment: I was asking about the case of the value passed to the converter. For troubleshooting purposes try converting value to string before passing to `Enum.IsDefined` and see if it works. ie `Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Enumerations.RelicTypes), value.ToString())`

Comment: @Nkosi yep that solves it post it as an answer so I can mark it

Comment: @Nkosi While the designer now works and the error is gone, the expect result is not seen at design time. Is this normal behavior in this case

Comment: What is the current and expected result at design time. please clarify.

Comment: @Nkosi to send a Uri to a Image Control with a path to a local .png Image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the `value` to a string before passing to `Enum.IsDefined` it should work provided that the casing of the enums match. According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Enumerations.RelicTypes), value.ToString())
```